# postgres with nodejs - how to return query result

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, asynchronous

I've had this problem before twice. The first time, it was because the returned object was actually an unfulfilled promise, and I was able to get around it by throwing all my code inside of the block so that it would execute in there. Not exactly an ideal solution but it worked and I was in a hurry.

The second time I was using `pg-promise` instead of just `pg`, and when this issue popped up I thought "it must be that damn promise again", so instead of tearing my hair out I just uninstalled `pg-promise` and went with the regular `postgres` package for `nodejs` instead. Well, the problem is still here and I'm tearing my hair out.

I'm making an API. I have a controller with functions such as `getPayment` and `postPayment` and so on. At some point in these functions, I need to get information from or into the database. In another file, which I called `postgres.js`, I have a connection to the database and then functions which I can call to insert data, select, etc.
Here is `postgres.js` as it is right now (this works but only for printing to console):

```
module.exports = {
    select: select

};

const { Client } = require('pg');


const client = new Client({
  user: 'myUser',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'myDB',
  password: 'myPassword',
  port: 5432,
});

client.connect();

function select(){
    client.query('SELECT * FROM payments', (err, res) => {
      console.log(err ? err.stack : res.rows[0].id);
      client.end();
    });
}
```

As you can see right now all it does is get the payments from the table and print a value (in this case, the first row's id) to console. 
Here is the code that calls this function, from the controller (`payments.js`):

```
var pg = require('../../config/postgres.js')

...

function getPaymentInfo(params){

 // get info from the DB

// disregard the fact that I'm not sending  any params right now, this is for testing
 var result = pg.select();
 console.log(result);
 console.log(typeof result);
}
```

Calling `pg.select()` does in fact activate the select function on `postgres.js` (and the console log correctly prints the data in `res.rows[0].id`) however when I try putting a `return res.rows[0].id` there in order to actually return the information that was retrieved from the database, what comes back into the `var result` is "undefined" according to the console. Here are a few examples of things I've tried to do to get the data out:

```
function select(){
        var i = '';
        client.query('SELECT * FROM payments', (err, res) => {
          //console.log(err ? err.stack : res.rows[0].id);
          i = err? err.stack : res.rows[0].id;
          client.end();
        });
        return i;
    }
```

I tried this with and without commenting the console.log line, either way it doesn't work.

```
function select(){
        client.query('SELECT * FROM payments', (err, res) => {
          //console.log(err ? err.stack : res.rows[0].id);
          return res.rows[0].id;
          //client.end();
        });
    }
```

I figure this would be wrong since I'm returning without checking for an error, but I tried just to see what would happen... `undefined` again.

```
function select(){
        client.query('SELECT * FROM payments', (err, res) => {
          //console.log(err ? err.stack : res.rows[0].id);
          return err ? err.stack : res.rows[0].id;
          //client.end();
        });
    }
```

This time checking for `err`, still returns `undefined`.

```
function select(){

    return client.query('SELECT * FROM payments', (err, res) => {
      //console.log(err ? err.stack : res.rows[0].id); // Hello World!

      client.end();
      return err ? err.stack : res.rows[0].id;
    });
}
```

Returning the return from `client.query(etc etc);`.. same thing as before. Also tried without the explicit return, without checking for error, all the same.

Here's the last test I tried:

```
function select(){
    var i = 'original i';
    client.query('SELECT * FROM payments', (err, res) => {
      console.log(err ? err.stack : res.rows[0].id); // Hello World!
      if (err){
          i = "i has changed!";
      } else {
          i = "i has not changed!";
      }
      client.end();
    });
    return i;
}
```

The console shows this:

```
original i
string
2
```

That last "2" being `res.rows[0].id`.

I really believe this must have something to do with the blasted "promises" and asyncronous stuff. But my previous "solution" won't fit here. I can't just do everything inside of that block where I have access to res. I **have** to be able to return some data back to `getPaymentInfo()`.

It seems that `client.query(...)` is waiting for every line in `getPaymentInfo()` to be ran before actually doing anything. I can see that because in the console, the results of `console.log(result)` and `console.log(typeof result)` appear before the line that shows information from the table (from `console.log(err ? err.stack : res.rows[0].id)` ). That is absolutely infuriating.

I called the `pg.select()` function. That function calls `client.query()`. `client.query` should do its thing, return to `select()`, which would then return to `getPaymentInfo()` and **then** keep going and do what the next lines say. That's normal behaviour for any program. Clearly that's not happening here.

I saw some examples out there that used `await`, but when I tried to add that copying the examples, it gave me a syntax error as if it didn't recognize what `await` is supposed to be. There was an example with `yield` as well, same error. It doesn't know what those commands mean. I'm using the latest version of nodejs (v8.10.0).

I also tried using `then` to get it to wait:

```
function generatePaymentInfo(params){
 ...

 pg.select().then(function(v) {
        console.log(v);
      });
...
}
```

It gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

What's going on here? How do I get it to do things in the right order? All I want is to get some information from a table. Every example for the `pg` package (and `pg-promise` as well) I see out there just has a `console.log()` representing "success". In reality what anyone would want is to have actual access to the data.

Comment: From your examples it is apparent that you do not understand how asynchronous code works, and you should not blame pg-promise or the pg driver for that. You make calls into asynchronous functions, and immediately return the result that doesn't exist yet, so of course you will be getting `undefined` everywhere. Sorry, but you need to look at the basics of asynchronous programming first.

Comment: @vitaly-t I apologize, I didn't mean to blame the tools. They're doing what they're meant to do, it's just not what I personally wanted. In any case, it turns out it's impossible to make it "not" asynchronous. I did find a package that sort of simulated synchronous behaviour, but I was short on time and ended up throwing the DB queries inside the controllers so that I could call the response directly and "solve" the problem, by not actually solving it. Not my proudest work, but I was in a big hurry.

Comment: Just pass a callback function to it.